# Assigning a global variable for a language switcher in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the issue.

I am calling LanguageSwitcher init, which in turn calls handlelanguage, which sets a language id ( either fr or us or es) (stores a cookie as well) , i have tried defining as a namespace and a global , but i cannot seem to be able to call the global from my index.html page script tag.

Anyone have a suggestion ?

## in index.html

```
<script>
   $.lang = new Object();
   $.lang.language='en';
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/language.js"></script>

    <script>

     jQuery(document).ready(function() {   
     LanguageSwitcher.init();

     });

    alert($.lang.language);
    alert(window.language);
    </script>
```

## in language.js

```
  var LanguageSwitcher = function () {

        var handleLanguage = function() {
         var id='fr';

          setCookie('language', id, 365);
          $.lang.language = id;
          window.language = id;

        });
      }

    return {

            //main function to initiate the module
            init: function () {
               handleLanguage();

            }


        };
}();
```

Comment: some code seem missed in language.js, there is "});" that should throw an error

Comment: Check your error console.  There are a few syntax errors and function setCookie is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I correct your code

```
$.lang = new Object();
$.lang.language = 'en';

var LanguageSwitcher = (function () {

    var handleLanguage = function () {
        var id = 'fr';

        //setCookie('language', id, 365);
        $.lang.language = id;
        window.language = id;
    };

    return {
        init: function () {
            handleLanguage();
        }
    };
})();

$(document).ready(function () {
    LanguageSwitcher.init();

    alert($.lang.language);
    alert(window.language);
});
```

---

http://jsfiddle.net/p762o0bt/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `setCookie()` function is defined and that `window.language` equal to `$.lang.language`.

```
$.lang = new Object();
$.lang.language= 'en';
window.language = $.lang.language;

jQuery(document).ready(function() {   
  LanguageSwitcher.init();
});

var LanguageSwitcher = (function () {

  var handleLanguage = function() {
    var id= 'fr';
    $.lang.language = id;
    window.language = id;
  };

  return {
    init: function () {
      handleLanguage.call(window);
      console.log($.lang.language);
      console.log(window.language);
    }
  }

})();
```

[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/zoxoyehoki/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {   
    LanguageSwitcher.init();
});

alert($.lang.language);
alert(window.language);
```

this will fire `LanguageSwitcher.init();` when the dom is ready. So the alerts are called before the initialization of your **LanguageSwitcher**

this should be like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {   
    LanguageSwitcher.init();
    alert($.lang.language);
    alert(window.language);
});
```